# iOS 13, disable clipboard features

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield, clipboard

I'm trying to disable cutting, pasting, copying, etc from the textfields in my app. From reading through stack overflow it seems that there are two ways to do this either through subclassing UITextField and using that custom class as your textfields or through extending UITextField. Since I want to disable this for all textfields I opted for the latter since it's simpler.

```
import Foundation

extension UITextField {
    override open func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
            return false
       }
}
```

Anyway, both methods seem to work fine on my test iOS 12 iPad, but do not work at all for my test iOS 13 iPhone 8... When I long press in iOS 13 the same options to cut past etc appear, meanwhile the behavior is as expected in iOS 12 where the user cannot access any of those menu items. What can I do to extend this functionality to iOS 13?

Comment: you have more fun subclassing UITextField, because you may want to use unchanged UITextField the classic way somewhere else. And you can still extend your new subclass then.

Comment: Sure, although it still wouldn't work in iOS 13. I've also tried something like:         class CustomUITextField: UITextField {
   override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste(_:)) {
            return false
        }
        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
   }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you where actually close to your solution.
As `UITextField` is still an Objective-C Class reading the class was easy to understand.

Selectors in Objective-C are written so..

```
@selector(methodname:)
```

corresponding in Swift

```
#selector(methodName(_:))
```

Where selector refers as `SEL` datatype pointing to a class method by name and the `:` means you explicit point to that method that takes an object or parameter. Because you could have a method with same name but without taking any object or parameter, which is by objective-c not an overriding rule but a total different method.

```
#selector(methodName()) // not same method as above
```

*So why did your solution not work?*
Your selector pointed to methods in general that are following the UIResponderStandardEditActions protocol. But you want the selectors of the implemented methods from your superclass in your subclass (or extension).

*Conclusion:*
This is what you probably wanted..

```
class SecureUITextField : UITextField {

    override func canPerformAction(_ action:Selector, withSender sender:Any? ) -> Bool {
        if  action == #selector(paste(_:)) ||
            action == #selector(cut(_:)) ||
            action == #selector(copy(_:)) ||
            action == #selector(select(_:)) ||
            action == #selector(selectAll(_:)) {
             return false
        }
        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }
}
```

*where to go from here?*
You could implement your own overriding functions of the inherited protocol `<UIResponderStandardEditActions>` paste(*:), copy(*:) and so on and let them do nothing. But you don't need to as long the coder using your class will follow the protocol and not make their total own target actions still making it possible to paste, select and copy.

Comment: Great, it works as desired thanks. Any insights as to why my code worked in iOS 12?

Comment: your first version returned false for all actions of UITextField where the extension was imported.